# Optional attribute in directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive with an isolate scope. Like this:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E'
        scope: {
            attr1: "=",
            attr2: "@",
            attr3: "&" 
        }, 
        template: 
            <div>

                <button ng-if="{true if attr3 is defined, otherwise false}"/>

            </div>

    };
});
```

One of the attributes - `attr3`, which is a callback - is optional. What I want to do is if the attribute exists, a button will exist, otherwise, the button is not there. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried `ng-if="optionalAttr"`?

Comment: And if previous comment don't work just force converting to boolean: ng-if="!!optionalAttr"

Comment: Nope. Both didn't work. Please note that `optionalAttr` expects a method.

Comment: Ah, well, then you should clarify in the question. :) I've edited your question to make it clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `p: "@"` and `p: "="` type parameters defined on the isolated scope, you could just do:

```
<div ng-if="p">p is defined</div>
```

For `p: "&"` this wouldn't work, because Angular assigns a callback function wrapper to this parameter, so it is always defined. To test if the attribute is not assigned, you could use the `attrs` parameter passed to the `link` function, like so:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
      scope.hasP = attrs.p !== undefined;
}
```

Then, in the directive's template you could do:

```
<button ng-if="hasP" ng-click="p()">
```

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rHtckfElRMt6XnSFK7ox?p=preview) to illustrate.